# How to show content from drop down(option)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

What i am trying to do is to create a user drop down list (option)

When a user select option from down down it will show its content/comment on a text area

```
<Option id="1"> Cancel </option>
<Option id="2"> Renew </option>     
<P><div id="1"> this is content of cancellation</p></div>
```

So when the user select the cancel it will show its content in a text area or pharagraph area

Comment: Please, include the code you have tried so far. Also, give a read to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Listen for a change on the `select` then set the `textContent` of the `div`:

```js
document.getElementById("select").addEventListener("change", () => {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").textContent = document.getElementById("select").value;
});
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option id="1" value="Cancel"> Cancel </option>
  <option id="2" value="Renew"> Renew </option>
</select>
<div id="myDiv">Replacement Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is `jquery` version, you should not use same id with option and div for cancel text.

I also recommend you use option with value instead of `id="1"`, in this case you did not set value for option so it get text as option value.

```
$("#myoption").change(function(){
      var selected = $(this).val();
      if(selected == "Cancel"){

        $('textarea').text($('#canceltext').text());
      }else{
        $('textarea').text(selected);
      }
    })
```

```js
$("#myoption").change(function(){
  var selected = $(this).val();
  if(selected == "Cancel"){
  
    $('textarea').text($('#canceltext').text());
  }else{
    $('textarea').text(selected);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myoption">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option id="1"> Cancel </option>
<option id="2"> Renew </option>    
</select>
<div id="canceltext"><p>this is content of cancellation</p></div>
<textarea></textarea>
```